# How to overwrite a column in a csv file using a different csv file

Tags: python, csv, join, merge, pandas

I am very new to python and I am totally stuck! I have two csv files that I am trying to combine into one csv file. Below are the first few rows of each file, including the actual output file and output file that I want to be getting. 
Note: I realize that the files do not match exactly (ie the CO_Num are not the same), but I just grabbed the first few rows each each file and they are not in order.

```
plat1.csv: 
District,Complex_ID,Structure_Num,Area,Block,Name,Long,Latitude,Operator,Status,Comments,CO_Num
4,90100,1,AC, 24, SSMANIFO,  -94.76940277,  26.95505833,,,,     ,      
4,183,1,AC, 25,  A-Hoover Spar,  -94.68872137,  26.93905139,,,,00276, 4825   
4,2008,1,AC, 857, A(Perdido),  -94.89791489,  26.12890071,,,,00689, 7835  


COMPAC.csv:
CO_Num,Operator
03249, LOUISIANA LAND AND EXPLORATION COMPANY LLC     
03267,145 OG HOLDINGS LLC                             
03271,157 OG HOLDINGS LLC             

plat2.csv
 ,90222,1,WR, 469, SS Manifold,  -90.53058044,  26.51964805,,,,     ,      
4,183,1,AC, 25,  A-Hoover Spar,  -94.68872137,  26.93905139,,,,00276, 4825   
4,10500,1,GA, 209, A,    -94.545972,    29.130363,,,,00276,   58 

desired plat2.csv
District,Complex_ID,Structure_Num,Area,Block,Name,Long,Latitude,Operator,Status,Comments,CO_Num
4, 90100,1,AC,24, SSMANIFO,-94.76940277,26.95505833,,,,                                                                
4, 183,1,AC,25,A-Hoover Spar,-94.68872137,26.93905139,EXXON MOBIL CORPORATION,,,00276                    
4,2008,1,AC, 857, A(Perdido),-94.89791489,26.12890071,SHELL OFFSHORE INC.,,,00689
```

I need to join the files based on the CO_Num column. The problem I am having is with the Operator column. In plat1.csv that column is empty, I need to use the COMPAC.csv file to fill it in. I tried using the code below, but it did not work. The Operator field was still empty in plat2.csv.

```
import pandas as pd

c=pd.read_csv("c:/platform/plat1.csv")

d=pd.read_csv("c:/platform/COMPAC.csv")

merged=c.merge(d, how='left')

merged.to_csv("c:/platform/plat2.csv", index=False)
```

I should also mention that not every line in plat1.csv has a CO_Num. I think that might be part of the problem, but when I re-ran after clipping plat1.csv and COMPAC.csv down to a single line in each (matching CO_Numb obviously) it still did not work.

After that I tried to re-run it again with the clipped files, but I removed the Operator column from plat1.csv. The was successful, but I need the Operator column to be in the position it is in in the plat1.csv, not at the end.

Basically, I need a way to join/merge these two csv files where the Operator column in plat1.csv is overwritten by what is in the COMPAC.csv file, and if there is no CO_Num, that line is simply empty in the Operator column(all other columns remain untouched).

Again I am very new at this, or if something doesn't make sense or if you have a question please let me know!

Comment: Are you required to use python?

Comment: yes, the boss said it had to be python. Not sure why, but I'm just following orders

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't include the empty Operator column of c in the merge (including it means merging on both CO_Num and Operator which means there are no shared keys):

```
merged = c[col for col in c.columns if col != 'Operator'].merge(d, how='left')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried your suggestion, but it did not seem to work. The Operator column is still empty, and the order of the columns is now different. I need the order to stay the way it is in plat1.csv, but instead I got:  Area,Block,CO_Num,Comments,Complex_ID,District,Latitude,Long,Name,Status,Structure_Num,depth,Operator

Comment: @Abby the operator column is still empty?? That's confusing. Can you append the head of the csvs (or some example frames which show this) to your question... I don't think it should be empty unless there are no CO_Num matches.

Comment: I went back and added a few lines from each file to my question. When I tried to run your edited code from above it told me that "failed to run script- syntax error- invalid syntax"